# How do I find & replace file contents in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I need to find text in a file, like:

```
PolicyFile=$(SrcRoot)BeHttp
```

and replace it with this:

```
PolicyFile=$(SrcRoot)PPCore/BeHttp
```

So I wrote following script but it's not working.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem 'D:\SomeFolder\\*.MKE' -Recurse | ForEach {
     (Get-Content $_ | ForEach  {   
       $_  -replace "PolicyFile=$(SrcRoot)BeHttp", "PolicyFile=$(SrcRoot)PPCore//BeHttp"
     }) | Set-Content $_
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to escape the characters powershell considers reserved.  Also, when using Get-Content, you need to provide full path. That path is available under FullName of the Child Item (Get-ChildItem).

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\SomeFolder\*.MKE' -Recurse | ForEach { 
        (Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace 'PolicyFile=\$\(SrcRoot\)BeHttp', 'PolicyFile=$(SrcRoot)PPCore//BeHttp' | Set-Content $_.FullName }
```

To Escape $ ( ), use `\`. Also, you dont need to use For-Each on string obtained from Get-Content.

**Update:**

When running `Get-ChildItem`, i do see all the files from all subfolders.

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-ChildItem 'C:\Temp\*.MKE' -Recurse | % { $_.FullName}
C:\Temp\1\new.mke
C:\Temp\2\3\new.mke
C:\Temp\2\new.mke
C:\Temp\new.mke
```

Comment: Ok, I tried using ` but still it's not replacing the string.

Comment: tried with your updated script but still, it's not replacing the content. And after running your script, it prints file content on PowerShell ISE console, I don't want to print that.

Comment: One more thing SomeFolder contains some subfolders and it also contains mke files. Currently, it's only working at the root level. So how to make replacement in a subfolder?

Comment: I created a folder with 2 level of subfolders, each with the same file. Tested the same code and it updates all the files.

Comment: @Rudra see my update in the post. I did a get-childitem and it shows all the files. I did get-content on each file as well and they all show updated content.